# Disable autoscroll top on insertRowBefore in a TableView in Appcelerator/Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

i'm currently using a TableView to display some elements in Appcelerator/Titanium.
The problem that i have is that when i make a pull to refresh and i call the method "**insertRowBefore**" to insert new elements at the beginning of the table using the method like following:

```
$.table.insertRowBefore(0,row);
```

The table auto scrolls to top, and it looks a little bit bad when there're a lot rows to insert, i want to keep the current position.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem it looks very ugly when inserting rows at table's top. I have managed this strange behavior by not inserting rows in table directly but inserting them to an array first :

```
//i suppose that you have an initial array contain your old rows oldRows
//add rows in the top 
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    oldRows.unshift(newRows[i]);
```

then set table's data

```
$.table.setData(oldRows);
```